# How to assign array element to string

Tags: button, nsstring, uipickerview, title

Hi I'm quite new to coding for iOs and can't get this to work. I try to make the label of a button change based on the array item of the PickerView that is selected.

```
(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{
NSString *buttonLable = [_characters objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
[titleButton setTitle:(NSString *)buttonLable forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

I think it has a problem with how I defined buttonLable as it says "@variable is not NSString".

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is syntactically correct, and your error message is thus output when you run the code.
The reason is the content of your array `_characters`. Since you can only assign an NSString object to `buttonLable`, the array element stored at index `[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]` has some other class. Just set a breakpoint at the assign statement an look for this class.